# Error in importing SimpleInputPrompt from llama index

Tags: nlp, llama-index

### Code:
from llama_index.prompts.prompts import SimpleInputPrompt

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from llama_index.prompts.prompts import SimpleInputPrompt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.prompts'

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.

I have already pip installed llama index on my colab notebook and a simple import of SimpleInputPrompt failed

Has the documentation changed? I dont find it anywhere in docs anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
from llama_index.core.prompts.prompts import SimpleInputPrompt
```

This has worked for me, so give it a try.
I faced the same issue and didn't find any documentation. I had to go to their GitHub repo to figure it out.